# Compiling with Babel: Is a preset-flag necessary when having a .babelrc-file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have learned and used the following syntax for compiling JavaScript-files using Babel:

```
babel main.js -o bundle.js --presets es2015
```

I haven't known about the existence of .babelrc-files until today.

Now my question ...

If I have a .babelrc-file with the following content:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

**Is the ' --preset es2015 ' flag still necessary when compiling from the command  line?**

**Or can I leave it? Just having ' babel main.js -o bundle.js '?
And Babel takes the further configuration out of the .babelrc-file?**

Comment: This is something you an easily find out yourself. Omit the flag, run the command and look at the generated files.

Comment: @FelixKling I would say with the .babelrc-file in the project folder it doesn't matter if you have the flag or you leave it out. But it's also just a small Javascript file. Not sure if it still works with really large files.

Comment: Why should the size of the files influence how babel reads its configuration options?

Comment: What I actually meant by that, was: Having just a small file I could compare each line. But with a large one that wouldn't be possible anymore. So I couldn't be sure that it doesn't have an effect leaving the preset-flag out. Grüße aus dem Saarland.

Answer (score 1):

[All `.babelrc` options are passed to the Babel API](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/). You can safely ignore the command line parameters if the .babelrc is in the working directory when you're running the `babel` command.